# What JAR contains the class MQSimpleConnectionManager

Tags: java, ibm-mq

Anyone knows what JAR?? Im going to implement a connection pooling for MQ series connection.

Comment: I'm using MQ JMS (IBM lib to put messages in a MQ Queue). The JAR containing the classes to access the Queues is mqjms version 1.5.6 version . I was trying to implement a connection pooling, following the reference [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/ja11240_.htm). I'm not sure if class MQSImpleConnectionManager belongs to a upper version of mqjms or if there is other jar containing it (I couldn't find at IBM documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jar is com.ibm.mq.jar
You can download it from http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/com.ibm/com.ibm.mq.jar.zip
Or if using maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mq</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.07</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using an older version from this jar, thats why I could not find this class (version 1.5.6). I was not sure if the class was contained in other jar or, as you posted, it belong to a newer version. IBM documentation ([reference](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/ja11240_.htm?lang=pt-br)) is not clear the minor version that supports MQSimpleConnectionManager resource

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this jar `com.ibm.mq.jmqi`.

Comment: The first and third sentences in your original answer would been better suited as comments to the question.